# Has someone successfully converted a yolov3-tiny model to Caffe?

Tags: python, caffe, darknet

I have been looking for ways to convert a custom trained yolov3-tiny network from darknet format to Caffe format, but every Python program I tried has failed. Has someone managed to do it and make it work? If so, what program or tutorial did you use and under which environment?

I have a machine with windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019 installed, and also a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04, in case that's any helpful.

Edit: these are some of the programs I've tried:

https://github.com/marvis/pytorch-caffe-darknet-convert

```
~/darknet2caffe/pytorch-caffe-darknet-convert-master$ python darknet2caffe.py ../yolov3-conos-tiny.cfg ../yolov3-conos-tiny.weights conos.prototxt conos.caffemodel
unknow layer type yolo 
unknow layer type upsample 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "darknet2caffe.py", line 350, in <module>
    darknet2caffe(cfgfile, weightfile, protofile, caffemodel)
  File "darknet2caffe.py", line 10, in darknet2caffe
    net_info = cfg2prototxt(cfgfile)
  File "darknet2caffe.py", line 251, in cfg2prototxt
    prev_layer_id = layer_id + int(block['layers'])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-1, 8'
```

https://github.com/BingzheWu/object_detetction_tools

```
~/darknet2caffe/object_detetction_tools-master/nn_model_transform$ python darknet2caffe.py ../../yolov3-conos-tiny.cfg ../../yolov3-conos-tiny.weights conos.prototxt conos.caffemodel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "darknet2caffe.py", line 6, in <module>
    from prototxt_utils import *
  File "/home/carlos/darknet2caffe/object_detetction_tools-master/nn_model_transform/prototxt_utils.py", line 151
    print('%s%s {' % (blanks, prefix), end = "\n", file = fp)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

https://github.com/eric612/MobileNet-YOLO/tree/master/models/darknet_yolov3

```
~/darknet2caffe/MobileNet-YOLO-master/models/darknet_yolov3$ python darknet2caffe.py ../../../yolov3-conos-tiny.cfg ../../../yolov3-conos-tiny.weights conos.prototxt conos.caffemodel
2
OrderedDict([('bottom', 'layer19-conv'), ('top', 'layer20-upsample'), ('name', 'layer20-upsample'), ('type', 'Upsample'), ('upsample_param', OrderedDict([('scale', '2')]))])
('upsample:', 20)
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:298] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 636:20: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "upsample_param".
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0518 13:14:19.206104 15199 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: conos.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am using Python 2.7 and have Caffe and Pytorch installed. I compiled the caffe library following this tutorial: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you please edit your post and show us some of the code you've tried as well as any accompanying error messages?

Comment: Edited. Hope this can be of any help. As I said in the edit, these are only some of the program I've tried. I'll keep looking for new ones.